# MD5 password hash with user lockout on failed login attempts

Tags: security, hash, cryptography, passwords, password-protection

I understand that an md5 salt+password hash is vulnerable to brute force attacks due to how fast the md5 hash can be generated. Does locking users out after multiple failed login attempts do anything to address this vulnerability?

My assumption is that the lockout feature is irrelevant in terms of the md5 speed vulnerability.  Moreover, I assume that one must first attain the password hash before attempting to break it using brute force.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. Account lockout is more about mitigating educated guessing or brute force over the internet. It also helps prevent someone from DoSing your server if your hashing algorithm **is** very expensive.

The weakness of MD5 comes from when you want to break the hash locally, usually after having stolen the database where the hashes are kept (or getting a dump of the hashes from the db). When it comes to attacking over the internet, the bottleneck comes from the network, not necessarily the algorithm. We still don't want people to be able to try, as people tend to use very weak passwords, and a dictionary attack could break someone's password in a reasonable amount of time... even over the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Lockout is probably not a bad idea, but as Gray mentioned, network speed will make a bigger difference unless and until an attacker gets offline access to the hashes.  The salt is a big help as long as the salts are stored separately from the hashes.  If they are not, then they will be stolen if and when the hashes are stolen so a dictionary attack can be used appending the salt to each dictionary "try".

A thing against which lockout does nothing is an attack in which the attacker does not care whose account he gets into, so long as he gets into one.  Then the attacker can pick the password to try and cycle through user names, never stressing the server enough to trigger the lockout.

Nevertheless, lockouts can be helpful.  Or a delay of, say, 5 seconds between tries.  For someone who needs to guess 5 times how he spelled his password, it is an inconvenience.  For an attacker, those 5 seconds times all the attack attempts he would have tried will be a major hassle.  Again, only as long as they cannot access your hashed passwords and your salts offline.

Comment: The salt is not meant to be secret and can be stored together with the hash. Don't mix up the salt with a pepper / server-side key, each has its own purpose.